# Why the layout in qt avoid to show full image of background image for pushbutton

Tags: qt, user-interface, layout

I have problem with layout. I put image for QPushButton background but when I add my button to each layout, it avoid to show full image.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use size Policy and minimum Height-width. for example you want to expand the button. first select the button and after that choose size Policy to change the size. select Expanding for each property(vertical|horizontal Policy) you want to change. Also you can set the vertical|horizontal stretch. if you want to set limit for it's size you can set minimum and maximum size for your button.
Just look at your object properties, Also look at [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html). :)